# QGIS Labelling misplaced

Tags: qgis, postgis, labeling

I'm developing a QGIS plugin along with PostGIS and I'm facing some problems with labeling. This plugin creates several layers and tables. Some of these layers are views  (labeling layers), so if I edit the one fo the source layer the view changes and then the label. I explain more detailed:

I have the following:

- One layer. Let's call it **layer1**.
- One none spatial table. Let's call it **table1**.
- One spatial view from these other two layers *layer1* and *table1* meant for labeling. Let's call it **labelView1**.

The point is this, when I edit *table1* adding a new element linked by a foreign key with *layer1*. The label position in *labelView1* changes into a messy thing. The Style of *labelView1* is the following:

- Symbol is a geometry generator. Since I want to create callouts from label to the geometry, wich is a point.
- The position of the label is saved on project. In the qgd file.

I have seen this behaviour in Windows10 and in Ubuntu. The QGIS version is 3.4, but I tried to move to the new 3.10 version of QGIS, with the callouts new feature, but is the same result.

As well I tried to reproduce it in a much simple way, but without succed, that's why I want to share a link with a GIF file showing this issue:

https://gifyu.com/image/vMY7

I've done the same but without fixed position,and the labels don't move, but the geometry_generator does.

Is there any way to prevent it if this is a bug?

Answer (score 1):

I reply myself.

Nop, is not a bug. What happened is the following. The labeling layer used the id in order to save the label position into the project database. Once the layer was updated, the id changed, and then all the labels sometimes, or some in others, switched positions with other geometries.

That was. Once I fixed the ID, the problem was solved.